# Return dataset in dataflow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Could I get ideas on retrieving the dataset using lookup method. Basically, my scenario as I have source data needs to lookup for other source table and on matching column from source I need to get all the records from other source data.

its a one to many relations. I tried Lookup but gives only one record on matching condition, OLE DB command don't retrieve any data as it will do only Insert/Update operations.

Thanks
prav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a Lookup Component then the two columns you match on must be exact. To clarify, if you are doing a Lookup on a varchar-type column and only finding one match it may be because there is only one exact match - trying doing a SELECT..FROM..JOIN..WHERE statement to confirm. If there are matches but they aren't going through the Lookup check your source data after it comes out of the OLEDB source (it may need to be trimmed).

If exact matching isn't necessary, you could try Fuzzy Lookup which allows you to specific how close (by giving a percentage) you want the matching columns to be.

Comment: Hi, This has solved using the script component, which will prepare the sql script then execute so in a single hit I could get the full result set as it is not possible with lookup to retrieve result set. On matching look up will return only one row even though multiple key matches. thanks prav

Comment: @praveen: A Fuzzy Lookup will also return multiple key matches but not in the way you were looking for =).

Answer (score 0):

This has solved using the script component, which will prepare the sql script then execute so in a single hit I could get the full result set as it is not possible with lookup to retrieve result set. On matching look up will return only one row even though multiple key matches. 
thanks 
prav